# C# Class construction for String Method

Tags: c#, string, class, constructor

I have a class with a couple of methods.

Here is my function mapping:

```
    public void Connect(string SourceFile, OleDbConnection Connection, OleDbCommand Command) { zConnect(SourceFile, Connection, Command); }
    public void Tablenames2cmb(OleDbConnection Connection, ComboBox TargetComboBox) { zTablenames2cmb(Connection, TargetComboBox); }
    public void Tablenames2cmb(OleDbConnection Connection, string Exclusion, ComboBox TargetComboBox) { zTablenames2cmb(Connection, Exclusion, TargetComboBox); }
    public string GetUser(OleDbConnection Connection, OleDbCommand Command, OleDbDataReader Reader, string username) { zGetUser(Connection, Command, Reader, username); }
```

The first 3 methods compile just fine. But the string methods gives me an error that there is no return.

Method:

```
    private string zGetUser(OleDbConnection Connection, OleDbCommand Command, OleDbDataReader Reader, string username)
    {
        string result = "Foo";
        return result;
    }
```

I guess I made a stupid mistake with the function mapping, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: zGetUser.. should be getuser?

Comment: That's not a constructor, it's a method, and the error message is right, you're not returning a value.  You need to return a value.

Comment: is that a typo `zGetUser` on the method?

Comment: @Servy You are totally right...I meant function mapping and not constructor. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return a string from the method GetUser. Its body has no return value:

```
public string GetUser(OleDbConnection Connection, OleDbCommand Command, OleDbDataReader Reader, string username) 
{ 
   return zGetUser(Connection, Command, Reader, username); 
}
```

Sometime a less clever formatting helps.

Comment: Oh dear...that's it. You're absolutely right. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I like when I can put everything on a single line, but I dislike a lot more to have to scroll to see the code.

Answer (score 2):

your method needs to return the value of the method it calls:

```
public string GetUser(OleDbConnection Connection, OleDbCommand Command, OleDbDataReader Reader, string username)
{ 
   return zGetUser(Connection, Command, Reader, username); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably missed return statement here

```
public string GetUser(OleDbConnection Connection, OleDbCommand Command, OleDbDataReader Reader, string username) { return zGetUser(Connection, Command, Reader, username); }
```